# How do I insert text into the footline of a specific slide in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I'm trying to insert references into a `beamer` footline. These references are different for each slide, so I cannot include them in the footline template - unless there is then some way to later define them per-slide.

I have tried to simply include the after a `\vfill`, but the location of the line then varies with each slide, and this is not what I want.

How do I insert references (or really, just any custom text) into the footline of a specific slide in `beamer`?

Comment: That's not really what the footline is for, is it?

Comment: I've used the term footline to make it easy to understand where I want to place the text, but you could consider the question as simply "How do I place text relative to the bottom of the page in beamer?"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This provides a new template/font/color `footline extra` and a macro `\footlineextra` to add text to the footline.

```
\documentclass{beamer}    
\title{Adding extra text to footline}
\author{R.J.~Drofnats}
\institute{University of St. Anford}

\useoutertheme{infolines}% for example, ymmv

\makeatletter
% add a macro that saves its argument
\newcommand{\footlineextra}[1]{\gdef\insertfootlineextra{#1}}
\newbox\footlineextrabox

% add a beamer template that sets the saved argument in a box.
% The * means that the beamer font and color "footline extra" are automatically added. 
\defbeamertemplate*{footline extra}{default}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,leftskip=\Gm@lmargin]{footline extra}
    \insertfootlineextra
    %\par\vspace{2.5pt}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{%
    % set the box with the extra footline material but make it add no vertical space
    \setbox\footlineextrabox=\vbox{\usebeamertemplate*{footline extra}}
    \vskip -\ht\footlineextrabox
    \vskip -\dp\footlineextrabox
    \box\footlineextrabox%
}
{}

% patch \begin{frame} to reset the footline extra material
\let\beamer@original@frame=\frame
\def\frame{\gdef\insertfootlineextra{}\beamer@original@frame}
\footlineextra{}
\makeatother


\setbeamercolor{footline extra}{fg=structure.fg}% for instance


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\maketitle\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{foo}
\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}
\footlineextra{Source: ``Mr. Lee'' by the Bobbettes}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{bar}
\begin{itemize}
\item Able
\item Baker
\item Charlie
\end{itemize}
\footlineextra{Source: \emph{What do People Do All Day?} by Richard Scarry}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{baz}
No footlineextra here
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Having spent an hour on this I must quit but a nice addition would be to make `\footlineextra` overlay-specification aware.

Comment: If you give the footline a background color by adding `bg=blue`, for example, to `setbeamercolor{footline extra}`, then you'll get a blue footline on every page, even when the footline has no content.  I want the background to appear only when the footline has content, so I have added `bg=\footlinebgcolor` to `setbeamercolor{footline extra}`, `\gdef\footlinebgcolor{blue}` to the argument of `\newcommand{\footlineextra}[1]`, and `\gdef\footlinebgcolor{white}` to the argument of `\def\frame`.  That works, although I don't know whether it's really the right way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Adding an alternative that doesn't use the footline template.  This is in response to the comment on my previous answer.  (Requires \usepackage{tikz})

```
\newcommand{\footlineextra}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[yshift=2ex,anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\hspace{2ex}#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Comment: This is a nice and simple approach. However, it produces an error when the extra text contains a linebreak. I replaced the `#1` with `\shortstack{#1}` and that seems to work around the issue. Not sure if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2):

I do this too, here's my hack that's roughly similar to the `tikz` approach posted earlier.

```
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\newcommand{\MyfootnoteBlock}[1]{%
  \begin{textblock*}{11cm}(1cm,9.1cm)%
    #1%
  \end{textblock*}%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{foot1}{<define footer 1 here>}
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{foot2}{<define footer 2 here>}
...
```

then before each frame

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[<foot name>]
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a real pain though. Is there any way to set it up so that I have a command to invoke in the frame? A bit like \frametitle{}, maybe something like \footlineextra{}?