# Place bibliography items at bottom of frame

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, biblatex, footnotes

Is there an easy way to add bibliography items to the bottom of a frame where they are referenced?

I am using Beamer and Biblatex.

Comment: Try http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5491/how-do-i-insert-text-into-the-footline-of-a-specific-slide-in-beamer (possible duplicate?)

Comment: I suppose biblatex's `\footcite` doesn't work as you want it to?

Comment: @Seamus: You should convert your comment into an answer. Perhaps refer to the `\footfullcite` command which always prints a full citation.

Comment: @lockstep OK. Now we're even

Answer (score 29, accepted):

BibLaTeX's `\footfullcite` (hat tip to lockstep) might do what you want.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{foo}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Here is text\footfullcite{jones00}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Will display the full reference to jones00 from the `foo.bib` bibliography.

Comment: As, I compile the code you described above. The citation is not printed in the end of slide. Instead it is printing whatever is inside the \footfullcite{jones00} i-e jones00 is printed. It is not picking the reference from ff.bib (as foo.bib is in the same folder). What would be the possible cause of it? thanks

Comment: Have you run biber and then latex again? In any case, this seems like a separate issue from the one discussed here.

Comment: \usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} solved my issue !

Comment: I am having same issue as kaka even with \usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

Comment: I was also having issues even when adding \usepackage[backend=bibtex]{bib latex}. In the following post, Joseph Wright suggests adding \makeatletter
\def\blx@maxline{77}
\makeatother after loading biblatex: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311426/bibliography-error-use-of-blxbblverbaddi-doesnt-match-its-definition-ve. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

%------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}
    Here is text \footfullcite{Vitay2014}. % this writes ref01 in footnote
    Here is text \fullcite{Vitay2014}. % this writes ref01 in place
    Here is text\footfullcite{Vitay2014}
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------

with the following bibliography entry 
@article{Vitay2014,
    title = {Timing and expectation of reward: a neuro-computational
    model of the afferents to the ventral tegmental area.},
    author = {Vitay, Julien and Hamker, Fred H.},
    journal = {Frontiers in Neurorobotics},
    year = {2014},
    volume = {8},
    number = {4},
    pages = {1--14},
}
```

It does not print reference in the footnote of the slide...

Comment: Welcome to TSE. How is this an answer?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/224668)