# Bibliography error: "Use of \blx@bbl@verbadd@i doesn't match its definition. \verb"

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Currently having problems with compiling my Master's thesis after downloading the newest version of TeXStudio and MiKTeX. The error message is as follows:

```
Use of \blx@bbl@verbadd@i doesn't match its definition. \verb
```

The only other place I found a similar question regarding this error message was found here:
[Biblatex: include bbl, problem with "verb" field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166518/biblatex-include-bbl-problem-with-verb-field)

I am not sure how this applies to my problem, but from what I understand this is due to some problem in an external file. If you need the bibliography-entry, I can provide you with that on short notice, though it is rather long (which is why I didn't include it here in the first place).

I am using Mendeley Desktop v1.16.1 to automatically generate my BibTeX database.

I am using biblatex as follows:

```
\usepackage[backend = bibtex,
        style = numeric-comp,
        sorting = none,
        natbib = true,
        doi = false,
        isbn = true,
        hyperref = true]{biblatex}
```

I also have some code to change how the bibliography output, but I doubt it is causing the problem, as commenting it out did not help.

Hope anyone knows what causes my problem and how to fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This bug is now fixed in `biblatex`: if you are experiencing it you should update your TeX system.

Following text is retained for historical record.

---

This is a bug in the BibTeX support for `biblatex` and is already fixed in the development version. As a temporary fix, adding

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@maxline{77}
\makeatother
```

after loading `biblatex` should work (after LaTeX/BibTeX/LaTeX).

---

The detail is that in order to update the BibTeX support to bring it into line with Biber, some additional items had to be added to the `.bbl` file BibTeX produces. This alters an indent, which needs to be set to correctly write verbatim material. Unfortunately I overlooked that in the earlier update.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and easy answer! It worked brilliantly! You have no idea how relieved I am right now.

Comment: I am having the same problem right now; unfortunately your fix doesn't work for me.

Comment: @user1488118 Please open a new question showing your issue: certainly the above does work for the case reported here.

Comment: the fix worked for me, after add the above section in my .tex file. thanks.

Comment: Worked for me too! (I forgot to compile bibliography beforehand, but now it's fine :) )

Comment: This saved my day, too, thanks a lot Joseph. I also had to add the above fix. Apparently the change didn't find its way into the MacTeX 2016 installation bundle for Mac yet.

Comment: I just updated my Tex distribution, however, I still have to use the fix.

Comment: @Amit The fix is in the public version: if you are still seeing the issue, please open a new linked question with details of your TeX system.

Comment: the fix didn't help, and I managed to make it work by removing all long URLs in my bib file (long enough to make multiple lines in the bbl file)

Answer (score 0):

Above solution did not work for me. I am using `svn41193-20120634` release on `openSUSE_Leap_42.2`. It is probably the latest release.

Following fixed it for me. On my bibliography file `bib.bib` I ran the following command.

`biber --tool -V bib.bib`

It generated a `_bibertool.bib` file in current working directory. I guess this tool also fixes the offending entries. I used this file in my latex file and everything compiled just fine.