# bibtex/biblatex citation Missing Number error

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

I've created a `.bib` file using Mendeley's bibtex export. I'm now trying to cite this source in my document. TeXmaker recognizes something, because it autocompletes the citation key for me.

But then when I try to compile, I get stuck with

> `! Missing number, treated as zero.`

errors on the citation line and a

> `! Use of \blx@bbl@verbadd@i doesn't match its definition.`

error with a line number that doesn't make sense.

Here are the contents of my `BibTex/library.bib` file:

```
@misc{Borowicz2016,
author = {Borowicz, Wojtek},
booktitle = {Estimote Community Portal},
pages = {3},
title = {{Apps and Projects with Estimote}},
url = {https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/207295257-Apps-and-projects-with-Estimote},
urldate = {Mar 3, 2016},
year = {2016}
}
```

Here's the MWE of my document I'm trying to get to work:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside, vi, letterpaper]{report} 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee]{biblatex} %style=numeric-comp
\bibliography{BibTex/library.bib}
\begin{document}

Hi! I am sample text.
Here is a citation: \cite{Borowicz2016}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
\endinput
```

This compiles fine if I comment out the citation line, but fails with it uncommented as shown. Suggestions on how to fix are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it really library.bib and you are asking for Library.bib on a system that is not case independent?

Comment: Note that your `urldate` field has the wrong format, date fields need to be filled in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, so you would have: `urldate = {2016-03-03},` instead.

Comment: Please check out [Bibliography error: “Use of \blx@bbl@verbadd@i doesn't match its definition. \verb”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/311426/35864). That solved the problem in your MWE for me. Note though that it is better to use the Biber backend instead of BibTeX. BibTeX is only supported as a "legacy backend" with a limited subset of functionality.

Comment: Can you confirm that the solution from the link above works for you as well?