# Distribute LaTeX projects with correct biber version

Tags: biblatex, biber

If I give a LaTeX project using biber to colleagues (maybe working on another platform) I often get the feedback that the biber part caused problems (for example because of version issues).

Whats the best way to deal with this problem? Maybe there is a way to include the correct biber version or something like that.

Comment: Do your colleagues compile from scratch or do you distribute auxiliary files generated by biber with the project?

Comment: Distributing Biber with your project would mean that you would also have to distribute `biblatex` since the versions of the two must be compatible. Distributing `biblatex` can easily mean distributing roughly 100 files (OK, you can probably reduce that if you only distribute the styles you need, at which point you might be violating the LPPL, but that might not be a big deal for you). But then `biblatex` has further dependencies - it is unlikely that you will have to distribute those as well: either the package has been stable for years ...

Comment: ... or the functions that `biblatex` needs have been with the package for quite some years now, but you never know. Distributing `biblatex` with the project might be inconvenient because you will need to make sure that LaTeX uses 'your' `biblatex` over the system version - that either means modifying environment variables, using command line options, or dumping the entire tree flat into the document directory. Neither options sounds great to me.

Comment: @TeXnician: Compiling from scratch. I just provide a git repository of my source files. Can you gives some details about how I could distribute (what) auxilliary files in a convenient way instead?

Comment: If you distribute temporary files, your colleagues may run into version troubles if they try to compile the document with your temporary files. If you don't distribute temporary files, they should normally be fine provided that their system has matching versions of `biblatex` and Biber and they manage to run Biber instead of BibTeX. And provided your document doesn't use fancy features that are not yet available for them.

Comment: I wanted to say the same as moewe said: Just distribute a plain version and do not use too recent features. Then you should be fine given that your colleagues have a working biber setup in general (which is also hard sometimes).

Comment: From experience on TeX.SX and other help forums there are two big problems: (1) calling/running Biber in the first place: Many people use editors that call TeX and related programmes at the push of some shiny buttons, but not all editors can tell whether to run BibTeX or Biber, so your colleagues will have to configure their editors to run Biber, this is covered at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 (Biber's job is explained very well at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 in case your colleagues want to know why they have to run Biber). ...

Comment: ... (2) Version incompatibilities: If your colleagues installed a complete TeX system this should usually not be a problem: `biblatex` and Biber will have been installed at matching versions (because they are usually uploaded at the same time and arrive in TeX live and MikTeX at the same time) and updates should update both packages. (a) Problems could arise if one of the two is not installed and has to be installed later, in that case the other package might be older. An update should help. (b) MikTeX multi-user installations could have problems if `biblatex` and Biber are installed ...

Comment: ... and hence updated with different users (User mode vs Admin mode). These problems would also apply to other packages where version dependency is crucial (some `expl3`/`l3` packages come to mind).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Distributing Biber also means distributing `biblatex`

If you want to distribute Biber with your project you must invariably also distribute `biblatex`, because the versions of the two must match.

### Distributing `biblatex` might mean distributing ...

The current `biblatex` version 3.11 also relies on `babel` being not older than 2016-04-23 (v 3.9r), and loads `xstring` from at least 2013-10-13 (v1.7c) and `etoolbox` from at least 2010-11-29 (v2.1).

Additionally, `biblatex` loads `pdftexcmds`, `keyval` (last updated in 2014), `kvoptions` (last updated in 2016, only doc changes according to the change history), `logreq`, `ifthen` (last updated in 2014), `url` (last updated in 2013). Most of these should probably be fine even in older versions, but I think I remember one of the key-value packages changing something that led to a problem with `biblatex`...

Versions of `polyglossia` older than 1.42.0 (August 2015) could also be problematic, but then `biblatex`'s `polyglossia` support is not great anyway and I would recommend to stick with `babel` if at all possible (see also the first part of my answer to [\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix, inheritance, and polyglossia in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432347/35864)).

So depending on how ancient your colleague's systems are you may have to distribute additional packages if you distribute `biblatex`. From the survey above `babel` is a really realistic candidate, most other packages are *probably* fine. Keep in mind that all other packages you distribute might also have additional version dependencies.

### Installation and use of the distributed versions

Even distributing `biblatex` is a bit of a complicated matter since the core together with the standard styles and localisation files weighs in at roughly one hundred files. You might try to cut down the number of files you distribute by only bundling the style files you need (I won't be using `debug.bbx`, so why should I ship it?), but that would probably (IANAL) violate the license conditions of the [LPPL](https://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt) (that might not be a big deal for a private project, it becomes more problematic when the project is publicly available; in any way it demonstrates that you would go against best practices).

Furthermore, your colleague's systems would have to find your version of Biber and `biblatex`. That means that you either need your colleagues to install your versions manually system-wide (or lets say semi-manually if you give them a script to do it), which is in general not recommended (and can have bad consequences if done incorrectly, for example if you write into a directory controlled by the TeX distribution updates might overwrite parts of your manual installation). Or you would have to mess with environment variables, command line include options, or put all files into the document folder. Neither of these options sounds particularly user-friendly or clean to me.

---

### So what can you do?

If you do not distribute the temporary files of your project (especially `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) your colleagues should be fine and can compile your project provided

1. they have `biblatex` and Biber installed in matching versions,
2. they know how to run Biber instead of BibTeX
3. the document does not use cutting edge features that requires everyone to have the newest `biblatex` versions.

Point 1 is usually not a problem on complete single-user installs. `biblatex` and Biber will have been installed with the system and if updates were performed (assuming your colleagues did not cherry-pick updates) `biblatex` and Biber were updated at the same time. Since `biblatex` and Biber usually go out to CTAN at the same time, they also arrive in TeX live and MikTeX at the same time (although there have been some troubles with that in the past).

Multi-user installations (especially MikTeX) can be problematic if `biblatex` and Biber were installed in different modes and updates are only done infrequently and in only one of the two modes.

It can also be problematic if your colleagues did not install a complete system and `biblatex` and Biber were installed on different dates without an update before the later installation. That could leave a system with versions that don't match.

The solution here is to ask your colleagues to make sure that `biblatex` and Biber are installed and then update their system properly and completely before they start to work on your paper. That sounds easy, but I am aware that that might be a huge ask: An update is always risky and people might be rightfully wary of updating before a deadline. On university or corporate hardware your colleagues might not even have the necessary rights to initiate an update. Lastly, the update must be complete ([How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864)), for multi-user MikTeX that means that it should be run in both admin and user mode (at least twice because critical system updates are prioritised, see also [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864)), for TeX live users it might mean installing anew version of TeX live ([Why does TeX Live "require" yearly updates?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107017/35864)).

Point 2 should be covered by [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) and a few minutes of your time in case one of your colleagues has questions about this.

Point 3 is not really an issue if your colleagues all have updated to the newest version. Otherwise you need to be aware of the fact that some things you might want to use were not available in earlier versions. You will probably be fine as long as you only use very high-level features. But if you begin to do some more serious stuff, a hard barrier is probably version 3.3 (March 2016, [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864)), for date handling 3.5 is relevant (September 2016), ...

#### Why this concern with temporary files?

Distributing the temporary files is usually more risky, because they were written by a particular version of `biblatex`/Biber and are only understood by that version. As soon as one of your colleagues runs a different version, things break - possibly with unhelpful messages. Since temporary files are meant to be regenerated, there is very little need to keep their format backwards compatible, see also [Matching biblatex in two machines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410512/35864).