# Automatically overwrite bbl for biblatex version conflict

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, automation

I work on a paper with a collaborator via git. Some of us have different latex versions, in particular `biblatex 3.9` and `biblatex 3.11` are used.

If author A compiles the document and runs biber, then a `doc.bbl` file with biber version 2.11 is created. If then author B makes some changes and tries to compile the error

```
Package biblatex Warning: File 'doc.bbl' is wrong format version - expected 2.9.
```

appears. The only solution at this point is to delete `doc.bbl` manually and recreate it in version 2.9.

Can one somehow automate this process? How can I tell my compiler to delete bbl files if a version mismatch is detected?

Comment: Why do you exchange the bbl via git? Simply put it in your .gitignore.

Comment: If both do a complete update ... Problem gone

Comment: I agree with Ulrike that there is no good reason to exchange the temporary files (not only `.bbl`, but also `.bcf`, `.aux`, ...). Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410512/35864. If you only share the `.tex` and `.bib` files you (1) have to share and transfer fewer files and (2) should both be able to compile with your local versions with less hassle.

Comment: Is there any latex solution to this problem? In other setting I sometimes collaborate via Dropbox or shared file servers where ignoring certain file extensions is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would avoid sharing the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) with your colleague. Only share the non-temporary important files (`.tex`, `.bib`, images, ...). See [Matching biblatex in two machines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410512/35864) for more explanations why sharing temporary files is usually bad and can go wrong.

Sophisticated systems like Git have a way to ignore certain files and so does Dropbox https://superuser.com/q/469776. Even if your preferred method does not have a way to selectively ignore a file, a simple script that delete temporary files before submission might be simpler here.

If you must share the temporary files, a simple clean-up script that get rids of temporary files before compilation (see for example [Deleting external/auxiliary files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24785/35864)) sounds like the best solution to me. Of course this file would not be called before every compilation, just before the first compilation after a sync. You could make the script cleverer by checking if the versions are wrong first (you'd have to parse the right part of the `.bbl` and would have to compare with the expected version of your `biblatex` installation, which seems possible, but fiddly).

Here is a LaTeX-based solution that overwrites `.bbl` files of the wrong version with an empty file by opening it and closing it immediately afterwards.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\blx@jul@deletefile@out

% copy of the original macro from biblatex.sty
\def\blx@ifsigned#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \let\blx@tempa\@firstoftwo
  \edef\blx@tempb{\csuse{blx@sig@#2}}%
  \edef\blx@tempb{\detokenize\expandafter{\blx@tempb}}%
  \openin\blx@bcfin #1.#2\relax
    \ifeof\blx@bcfin
    \else
      \endlinechar\m@ne
      \readline\blx@bcfin to \blx@tempc
      \ifeof\blx@bcfin
      \else
        \ifx\blx@tempb\blx@tempc
          \readline\blx@bcfin to \blx@tempc
          \edef\blx@tempb{\csuse{blx@ver@#2}}%
          \edef\blx@tempb{\detokenize\expandafter{\blx@tempb}}%
          \ifx\blx@tempb\blx@tempc
          \else
            \blx@warning@noline{%
              File '#1.#2' is wrong format version - expected \blx@bblversion}%
            \let\blx@jul@deletefile@do\@empty% <- added
          \fi
        \else
          \blx@error
            {File '#1.#2' not created by biblatex}
            {This file was apparently not created by biblatex.
             Rename it or\MessageBreak move it to a location were
             TeX will not find it. If this error\MessageBreak
             persists, consider redefining \string\blxauxsuffix.%
             See the biblatex\MessageBreak manual for details}%
          \let\blx@tempa\@secondoftwo
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \closein\blx@bcfin
  \ifundef\blx@jul@deletefile@do% <- this conditional is new
    {}
    {\blx@warning@noline{Deleting file #1.#2}%
     \immediate\openout\blx@jul@deletefile@out #1.#2\relax
     \immediate\closeout\blx@jul@deletefile@out
     \global\undef\blx@jul@deletefile@do}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\blx@tempa}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I wouldn't do that, but if you insist on a LaTeX solution this is pretty universal.