# Configuring Texmaker for BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, texmaker

I'm trying to write my first LaTeX document, but I'm getting a wired error message with regards to using Texmaker to use `biblatex`. Whenever I try to compile my code the log highlights my `\begin{document}` line and states the following:

> ```
> ! Package biblatex Error: file "'Document name".bbl' not created by biblatex.
> ```

Where `"Document name"` is the name of my LaTeX file.

Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathtools,amssymb, amsthm}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style = authoryear
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}
```

Strangely, my test document for `biblatex` does work, which has the source code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend = biber,
    style = authoryear
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{RFCN-citations.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a text for bibLaTeX. \cite{HistOfMaths}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I'm using Texmaker v5.0.2 and Windows 10 as my environment. I've made sure to configure Texmaker, as per the following screencaps:

[image: Texmaker configuration, Commands]

[image: Texmaker configuration, Quick Build]

[image: Texmaker configuration, Editor]

I've been trying for 3 days now to get some sort of automated references within my document via some LaTeX package, and it's really starting to drive me insane.

Comment: Delete the `.bbl` file. This was generated with another programme (probably `BibTeX`). If you delete it, it will be recreated by Biblatex on the next run.

Comment: Off-topic: best steer clear of `tabu`.

Comment: @cfr I can't believe that actually worked. I just stunned as to how Texmaker or LaTeX would be stupid enough to generate a file that breaks it. Thanks a bunch cfr!

Comment: You ran `bibtex` on the file. Or you told TeXmaker to run it. Nothing to do with LaTeX. Probably `bibtex` is default. You likely changed it to Biber. But then you're left with the file generated by BibTeX.

Comment: Just to make sure that the link to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 is here.

Comment: @cfr Do you want to type up an answer, or should be close this as *solved by deleting aux files*?

Comment: An error or warning is no sign of stupidity. LaTeX (or packages) run sanity tests, so you don't make stupid mistakes by accident. Everytime you see a warning or error (in any program) somebody was thinking about possible situations and how to handle them. Alternative to errors: Files get deleted, overwritten, the program or computer stops working out of nothing. Errors and warnings are great. *Do you really want to delete this file?* is also a *warning*.

Comment: @moewe Is there a good duplicate? This is quite a common issue, so I think it is worth having an answer. But I'm guessing there's a good answer already. If not, I can type one, sure.

Comment: @cfr I could not find something good, though I assume there must be a duplicate out there. So it would help if you could write up something here.

Comment: @moewe We have the generic delete all aux files and  start over and the how to use biber with editor question.  This one would fit both.

Comment: @Johannes_B OK, I would be fine with a delete all aux files here, but I couoldn't find it. Can you add a link? The Biber editor question is relevant (especially given the title), so I already linked it here, but it does not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @Johannes_B But it is the `.bbl` specifically which needs to be deleted. I don't know what 'delete all aux files' means. Should it be 'delete all generated files'?

Comment: @moewe You could surely write a better answer, but, for what it is worth, I had an inelegant go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you first compile your `.tex` file, you produce some other files with information about the bibliography. You then run another tool to produce a `.bbl` file. That file is then read back when you recompile your document to produce the bibliography and citations.

But the format of the `.bbl` file depends on the tools you're using to generate the bibliography.

- If you use BibTeX, the `.bbl` has a pretty straightforward format, which looks pretty much as your bibliography would look if you entered it by hand using the `thebibliography` environment.
- If you use Biblatex and Biber, the `.bbl` has a very different format, which looks nothing like code for your bibliography would look if you entered it manually. This is because Biblatex parses this file in a much more sophisticated way.

The upshot of this is that whether you use Biblatex/Biber or BibTeX, the `.bbl` is read in when you recompile the document but, the format of that file has to match the tools you're using.

So, if you initially run `bibtex <filename>` to produce a `.bbl` and *then* try to recompile the document with a `\usepackage{biblatex}` line, Biblatex will find that the `.bbl` has the 'wrong' format. This can happen because you explicitly run `bibtex` or it can happen because your editor is configured to run `bibtex` automatically whenever you compile a document.

Whatever the cause, Biblatex will find that the `.bbl` format is the old-style format which looks like code for your bibliography, rather than the new-style format which doesn't and which Biblatex expects.

Hence, Biblatex will give you an error because it is faced with a `.bbl` which it knows is designed for a different bibliographic tool-set.

The point is that Biblatex will not overwrite or remove a file which you might not want it to, because that might be pretty bad. Instead, it tells you about the problem so that you can decide what to do.

What you typically want to do is to simply delete the `.bbl` file, recompile the document and run `biber` to generate a `.bbl` with the correct format. Then, when you recompile again, Biblatex will find a `.bbl` in the format it expects.

Comment: +1) [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) also has a very good explanation about the general workflow with bibliography backends. If you wanted, `biblatex` could delete `.bbl`s not created for it automatically: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440473/35864 (that question is about `.bbl`s in the wrong version, but the same strategy could be applied here). But letting `biblatex` delete auxiliary files on a whim is a bit too dangerous for my liking.