# LaTeX issue with citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Hi all I am working on a citation for my whitepaper I used https://www.mybib.com/ to generate my .bib file. However I can't get the citation to show

Here is the code in my LaTeX file

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{biblatex}

 \addbibresource{References.bib}

 \begin{document}
 Someone must have found a simple solution  \cite{references}.
 \printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

Here is my References.bib file

```
 @misc{references,
   month = {09},
   title = {bibliographies - How do I add "citations" at the end of the document as done here?},
   url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134180/how-do-i-add-citations-at-the-end-of-the-document-as-done-here},
   urldate = {2020-05-01},
   year = {2016},
   organization = {TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange}
 }
```

Here is the output of the code 
[image: output]

I am using ubuntu, texmaker and all files are in the same directory

Running F11 bibtex in TexMaker I get the following error

Process started

```
 This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017/Debian) The top-level auxiliary file: Using References-bib.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file Using References-bib.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Using References-bib.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Using References-bib.aux (There were 3 error messages)

 Process exited with error(s)
```

I'm not sure if I am missing anything else THANKS ALL!!!

Comment: Did you run biber on your .tex file? (See also: [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/134144))

Comment: Look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442267/configuring-texmaker-for-biblatex to see how to configure texmaker for biblatex

Comment: TexMaker looks to be configured correctly

Comment: @KyleSponable Clearly it's not, since your error shows you ran `bibtex` not `biber`. These are two distinct bibliography processing programs.