# Visual Studio Code Delete bbl

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, latex-workshop, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code LaTeX workshop. My objective is the same as in [Automatically overwrite bbl for biblatex version conflict](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440473/automatically-overwrite-bbl-for-biblatex-version-conflict). Is there any mechanism specific to Visual Studio Code such that, after each compile of the project, the Visual Studio Code deletes automatically the .bbl file?

Comment: Why can't you use moewe's solution? Note that the issue there has to do specifically with collaboration. If you delete the `.bbl` after every compilation, you will never generate a final version of your document.

Comment: Generally, it's a very bad idea to delete auxiliary files like the `.bbl` after a compilation. It makes the next compilation sequence (usually unnecessarily) longer. Sometimes it can be necessary to delete auxiliary files to get out of a very bad error loop, but that should happen rarely enough that it can be done by hand. Cases like the one in the linked questions are really the exception. Why do *you* want to delete the `.bbl` file?

Comment: That all said, it should be easy enough to write a shell script that deletes a `.bbl` file and call that in your editor. (Writing the shell script would be more on topic on a site like https://stackoverflow.com/.)