# Inserting bibliography .bbl directly into .tex file causes Undefined control sequence

Tags: biblatex, errors, overleaf, undefined

I'm trying to submit a paper online, and it causes errors BibTex since the online compiler only runs a single pass of pdfLaTeX. The journal recommends including the .bbl directly into the .tex file, and since I'm using Overleaf, I followed [these](https://www.overleaf.com/help/219-the-journal-says-dont-use-bibtex-paste-the-contents-of-the-bbl-file-into-the-tex-file-how-do-i-do-this-on-overleaf#.W6aCyGhKiUl) directions. Unfortunately, I get **Undefined control sequence** errors on the copy-pasted .bbl text.

---

**My Code**

```
\documentclass[titlepage, 10pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{
  \chapter*{\bibname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}}{
  \section{References}}{}{}
\makeatother

...

\let\stdsection\section
\def\section*#1{\stdsection{#1}}

\printbibliography[title={References}]

\let\section\stdsection
```

I comment out everything from `\addbibresource{sample.bib}` to `\makeatother` and everything from `\let\stdsection\section` to `\let\section\stdsection`, then I paste in the contents of the .bbl file below the `...`.

---

Among other issues, the first error I get in Overleaf is

> l.401   `\sortlist[entry]{nty/global/}`
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never `\def`'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx`'), type `I`' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox`'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

What am I missing? The explanation didn't mention that I had to include any extra packages once I copied the .bbl file over, but now it looks like there's thousands of undefined control sequences.

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864 which is specifically for `biblatex`. The Overleaf page you linked to is for BibTeX only. The approaches of BibTeX and `biblatex` are different and require different uses of the `.bbl` file. Even if you get your file to compile, chances are the publisher cannot accept a `biblatex` submission.

Comment: I double-checked that the way described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864 still works in principle. But as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410512/35864 and elsewhere, `biblatex` is *extremely* sensitive to version changes in the `.bbl` file. That means that this can only work if your `biblatex` version and the version that your publisher uses are the same. That is quite unlikely.

Comment: @moewe Would you recommend I use BibTex instead?

Comment: If you mean to use `backend=bibtex` instead of `backend=biber` as option for `biblatex` then no: That won't really bring any measurable improvement in general. If you mean to drop `biblatex` entirely and go back to BibTeX's `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` (and `cite` or `natbib` if you like), then yes that is the far better option for journal submissions. (But even there you should double check the author guidelines of your publisher.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instructions from Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/help/219) are specifically for use with BibTeX-based bibliographies. [Herbert's answer to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12185/35864) [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864) explains how you could do something similar with `biblatex`.

For most intents and purposes, however, that will not work as intended. Unlike with BibTeX-based bibliographies, where the `.bbl` file contains ready-to-typeset material, `biblatex`'s `.bbl` files contain the rehashed raw data in a LaTeX-readable format. The exact format of `biblatex`'s `.bbl` file will depend on the `biblatex` and Biber version. The `.bbl` file on your machine can only be understood by systems with the same `biblatex` version (well, actually the same internal `.bbl` file version; `biblatex` development is still ongoing, so there is no stable state of affairs yet). See [Matching biblatex in two machines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410512/35864), [Making the arXiv accept a BibTeX BBL (May 2018)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429436/35864) and [Which biblatex/biber version produces BBL format 2.8?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415703/35864) for more background on this.

In fact copying `biblatex`'s `.bbl` file into your `.tex` document makes your document *less portable*. By using internal commands in your `.tex` file you effectively restrict the possible versions of `biblatex` that you could use, because `biblatex` is sensitive to changes in these internal macros. The user interface on the other hand is stable when it comes to high-level features and changes are usually attempted in a backwards compatible way (unfortunately, that does not always work out). So while it is possible to include a `biblatex` `.bbl` into a `.tex` file it usually does more harm than good.

Additionally, it is not guaranteed that publishers can deal with `biblatex` submissions anyway (see [Joseph's answer to *Biblatex: submitting to a journal*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12179/35864)). For journal submissions it is usually safer to use the provided classes (if any) or use standard classes and simple BibTeX or a manual `thebibliography`.

**The bottom line is that for journal submissions your best chance is still good old BibTeX with `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography`.**

The difficulties with the arXiv demonstrate that if publishers want to support `biblatex` they should accept uploading `.bib` files. User-submitted `.bbl` files only cause version conflicts and pain. That would mean, however, that they would have to run LaTeX and Biber on the submitted files, which would significantly complicate their workflow. I don't see that happening any time soon.

<sub>Note that using BibTeX as backend for `biblatex` has the same issues as using Biber since the use of the `.bbl` file is the same and the format is only very slightly different, so simply switching to `backend=bibtex` in `biblatex` will not bring measurable improvement.</sub>