# Footnote in block statement

Tags: beamer, environments, footnotes

I have a presentation to make, and in this I present a quote in a block, like this:

```
\begin{block}{Quote headline} 
Some truly great words some man made before me.
\end{block}\footnote{And this is where the man made his words}
```

Unfortunately, Latex destroys the layout in such a way, that the footnote index is shown in a new line, not right after the block.
My first try was to put the footnote into the block. In that case, the footnote itself was shown in the block, but I'd like to have it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: See http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=footintab. I'm not 100% if this also applies for `beamer` `block`s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the combination of `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` referred to by Martin Scharrer -- it also works for `beamer` blocks. In the following example, I added some code (from [beamer: footnote text collides with navigation symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5852/beamer-footnote-text-collides-with-navigation-symbols)) for placing the footnote above the navigation symbols.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Code for placing the footnote above the navigiation symbols
\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{\vspace{-6pt}\advance\hsize-0.5cm}{\vspace{6pt}}
\makeatletter
% Alternative A: footnote rule
\renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern -3pt \hrule \@width 2in \kern 8.6pt}
% Alternative B: no footnote rule
% \renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern 6pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A frame}
\begin{block}{Quote headline} 
Some truly great words some man made before me.\footnotemark
\end{block}
\footnotetext{And this is where the man made his words}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternatively, using the `frame` option, as in `\footnote[frame]{<text>}` generates exactly the same output. This is described in section 12.12 of the manual for version 3.26.