# Wrong numbers when using \footnotemark

Tags: beamer, numbering, footnotes

When adding a footnote to a **frame title** in Beamer using [the code from another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22323/footnote-in-block-statement), I get wrong numbering. Here you can see 1 above and 0 below:

[image: Wrong numbers]

This is an imaginary example. In reality, I need footnotes to cite the source of the material.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22323/footnote-in-block-statement
\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{\vspace{-6pt}}{\vspace{6pt}} 
\makeatletter 
 \renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern -3pt \hrule \@width 2in \kern 8.6pt} 
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}{SCLP example\footnotemark}
         \footnotetext{To be continued.}
         An example of a soft constraint logic program.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There is a related question ["Enumeration of footnotes wrong"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25473/enumeration-of-footnotes-wrong), but if I add

```
\addtocounter{footnote}{+1}
```

before the text of my footnote, I get wrong enumeration once again: 2 above and 1 below.

On the other hand, I tried to replace numbers with stars in the whole document [as described here](http://help-csli.stanford.edu/tex/latex-footnotes.shtml):

```
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{ctr}}
```

However, pdfLaTeX wouldn't compile this code.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 7):

This might form part of how the frame title is set. In fact, looking at your analysis, it is clear that the frame title is set *after* the frame contents. As such, avoiding insertion of counter-related commands in the title might be a workable quick-fix.

Here I've forced the counter to be incremented (`\stepcounter{footnote}`) to allow for correct display when using `\footnotetext`, and only typeset the number in the frame title using `\textsuperscript{\thefootnote}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer

%\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22323/footnote-in-block-statement
\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{\vspace{-6pt}}{\vspace{6pt}} 
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern -3pt \hrule \@width 2in \kern 8.6pt} 
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{SCLP example\textsuperscript{\thefootnote}}
  \stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{To be continued.}
  An example of a soft constraint logic program.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

At least in your example, `\footnote` works inside the frame title.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22323/footnote-in-block-statement
\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{\vspace{-6pt}}{\vspace{6pt}} 
\makeatletter 
 \renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern -3pt \hrule \@width 2in \kern 8.6pt} 
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}{SCLP example\footnote{To be continued.}}
         An example of a soft constraint logic program.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: In response to your comment: Try to insert the following code snippet in your "full" document:

```
   \begin{frame}{SCLP example\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\footnotemark}
         \stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{To be continued.}
         An example of a soft constraint logic program.
   \end{frame}
```

Comment: Indeed. But in my full document `\footnote` adds the footnote exactly in the same block with the title and not in the footer. I think, it's style-dependent.