# footnote ordering in beamer within a single frame using columns

Tags: beamer, footnotes, columns

I have a frame with two footnotes. One is in the frame title using `\footcite` and the second in a column (using `\footnotemark`). Unfortunately the order is mixed up as the second footnote in the column text gets numbered 1, and the first in the frame title is numbered 2.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test1,
title = {My first Title},
author = {T the First.},
year = {2006}
}
@article{test2,
title = {My second Title},
author = {TT the Second.},
year = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=verbose,giveninits=true,mincitenames=3,autolang=hyphen,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{My Frame title \footcite{test1}} %<-- should be number 1
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item left first
\item left second\footnotemark %<-- should be number 1
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item right first
\item right second
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\footcitetext{test2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I managed to get the numbering correct using `\addtocounter{footnote}` but then the footnote order is still wrong (2 above 1).

Comment: Problem still persists for `\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My Frame title \footnote{test1}} 
  \footnote{test2}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
`

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46560/wrong-numbers-when-using-footnotemark

Comment: I am a bit confused: the comment in the code tells that the footnotemark in the columns `%<-- should be number 1`?

Answer (score 4):

Would this work? (based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46562/36296)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{test1,
        title = {My first Title},
        author = {T the First.},
        year = {2006}
    }
    @article{test2,
        title = {My second Title},
        author = {TT the Second.},
        year = {2012}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=verbose,giveninits=true,mincitenames=3,autolang=hyphen,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{My Frame title\setcounter{footnote}{0}\footnotemark}
        \stepcounter{footnote} \footcitetext{test1}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item left first
                    \item left second\footnotemark %<-- should be number 1
                \end{itemize}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item right first
                    \item right second
                \end{itemize}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
        \footcitetext{test2}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This assumes there is only one footnote in the frame body.  Better to set the counter to `0` in the frametitle.

Comment: @AndrewSwann You're right! Thanks for comment, I edited my answer.

Comment: This seems to work only with some bib styles… With `trad-abbrv`, for example, only the number of the publication appears in the footnote.

Comment: To fix the issue I mentioned, just use `\footnotetext{\fullcite{}}` instead of `\footcitetext{}`.