# How can I stop \footcite from hijacking my beamer columns?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes, columns

I have prepared a `beamer` presentation for a seminar. I already have presented, but in trying to change traditionally-cited references (with a number superscript and the reference typesetted at the end of the presentation), I used `biblatex`'s `\footcite`. Consider this frame snippet:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}  
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[style=verbose,autocite=footnote,maxnames=10,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backend=biber,mcite]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\setlength{\columnsep}{.2cm}
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme[width=4em]{PaloAlto}
  \usecolortheme{crane}
}
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Sub} 
\author[me]{me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

    %%%%%%% MAIN CODE %%%%%%
\begin{frame}{The FDTD Method}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item Discretization of both space and time by central differences.
                \item Yee Cell %\footcite{Taflove2000}. 
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{some_figure}
          \caption{Unit Yee Cell.}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}

    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Put any PDF, PNG or JPG file named `some_figure` together with this `.tex` file. The content of the `references.bib` file (just to enable compilation) are:

```
@Book{Taflove2000,
    Day = {{30}},
    Edition = {{2nd}},
    Month = {{jun}},
    Publisher = {{Artech House Publishers}},
    author = {Taflove, Allen and Hagness, Susan C.},
    title = {{Computational Electrodynamics: The Finite-Difference Time-Domain Method}},
    year = {{2000}},
}
```

With the comment in place (that is, when not citing with `\footcite`) the second column containing the figure appears in the PDF output correctly. But, when the comment is removed, the citation appears at the footer of the frame, but the second column goes into oblivion along with the figure. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, add a minimal preamble in order that the code can be compiled.

Comment: It's the usual problem of footnotes in tabular material; you should use `\footnotemark` in the `column` environment and `\footcitetext{Taflove2000}` after `\end{column}`, but the result is not pretty.

Comment: @egreg thanks a lot! It is certainly not a general solution, but hey, it works!. Are we waiting for someone to come up with the general solution as the answer for this question?

Comment: I'm not at all satisfied with the position of the footnote, are you? But I'm not an expert in these Beamer details.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One can avoid the problem by using the `\footnotemark`-`\footnotetext` mechanism:

```
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Discretization of both space and time by central differences.
    \item Yee Cell\footnotemark
  \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\footcitetext{Taflove2000}
```

However this poses another problem: the text of the footnote may go over the navigation symbols, so another adjustment suggested by lockstep is needed (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5861/4427)): the following code should go in the preamble

```
\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{\vspace{-6pt}\advance\hsize-0.5cm}{\vspace{6pt}}
\makeatletter
% Alternative A: footnote rule
\renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern -3pt \hrule \@width 2in \kern 8.6pt}
% Alternative B: no footnote rule
% \renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern 6pt}
\makeatother
```

Choose your pick. I've modified the code adding also something for reducing the text width for the footnotes, or they will go all the way to the margin.

There are some errors in your `.bib` entry:

```
@Book{Taflove2000,
    Day = {30},
    Edition = {2nd},
    Month = {jun},
    Publisher = {Artech House Publishers},
    author = {Taflove, Allen and Hagness, Susan C.},
    title = {{Computational Electrodynamics: The Finite-Difference Time-Domain Method}},
    year = {2000},
}
```

Too many braces: Biber and biblatex are not able to understand properly the data.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the .bib formatting for biber processing. I'll be correcting the file for that.

Comment: @LuisE. Note that the content of the `edition` field normally should be an integer with `biblatex`.

Comment: Sadly this only works if you have a single citation. If you have more than one, the footcitetext will show the wrong counters. For example it will show 1 and 2 in the citation, but 2 and 2 in the footer.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a complete example incorporating the fixes proposed by egreg and me:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[width=4em]{PaloAlto}
\usecolortheme{crane}

\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{\vspace{-6pt}\advance\hsize-0.5cm}{\vspace{6pt}}
\makeatletter
% Alternative A: footnote rule
\renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern -3pt \hrule \@width 2in \kern 8.6pt}
% Alternative B: no footnote rule
% \renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern 6pt}
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}  
\usepackage[style=verbose,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Taflove2000,
    Day = {30},
    Edition = {2},
    Month = {jun},
    Publisher = {Artech House Publishers},
    author = {Taflove, Allen and Hagness, Susan C.},
    title = {Computational Electrodynamics: The Finite-Difference Time-Domain Method},
    year = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{The FDTD Method}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Discretization of both space and time by central differences.
      \item Yee Cell.\footnotemark 
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \rule{0.9\columnwidth}{2cm}% placeholder for graphic
      \caption{Unit Yee Cell.}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\footcitetext{Taflove2000}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting use of the filecontents package, I didn't know about it. Thank you!

Comment: How about two footnotes on the same page? How can one name them in order? Both of them are displayed in the footer with the number 2 before them.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solutions listed inadequate. When I used it, the numbering of the footnote was inconsistent with the bottom, and there is also the problem with multiple footnotes. A bit more googling (and [Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86650/how-to-display-the-footnote-in-the-bottom-of-the-slide-while-using-columns))  allowed me to find the following solution:

```
\footnote[frame]{\fullcite{AlnaesBlechta2015a}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Often it is very useful for readers to see a complete full example and not just the partial solution so to easy replicate it.

Comment: This works great, and unlike the accepted answer it even works with multiple citations!