# How to display the footnote in the bottom of the slide while using \columns?

Tags: beamer, captions, footnotes

I am using `\columns` in `beamer` to show two pictures. After I added `\footnote{ExampleText}` after captions, the `ExampleTest` just appear in each column. Now I want to show all of the `ExampleText` in the bottom of the slide instead of each column, how can I do this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics{img1}\footnote{f2}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics{img2}\footnote{f1}
\end{column} 
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use `\footnotemark`, `\footnotetext{<text>}`; a little example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}
Some text for the first column and a test footnote\footnotemark
\column{.5\textwidth}
Some text for the second column and a test footnote\footnotemark
\end{columns}
\footnotetext[1]{A test footnote in the first column}
\footnotetext[2]{A test footnote in the second column}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In a comment it has been asked how to use the same footnote text for two footnotes, one in each column; here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}
Some text for the first column and a test footnote\footnotemark
\column{.5\textwidth}
Some text for the second column and a test footnote\footnotemark[1]
\end{columns}
\footnotetext{A test footnote for both columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have the footnotes appear at the same time as the item they belong to? Maybe something like `\only<3->` to have the footnote appearing with the third item on the slide, but not before?

Comment: @MatthiasBraun You can have `\footnote<.->{Some text}` and `\footnote<3->{Some text}` etc.

Comment: To avoid to update footnote numbers by hand one can add at the beginning of the slides the code \newcounter{savedfootnotenumber}
\setcounter{savedfootnotenumber}{\number\value{footnote}}  and then  \addtocounter{savedfootnotenumber}{1}\footnotetext[\value{savedfootnotenumber}]{First note}\addtocounter{savedfootnotenumber}{1}\footnotetext[\value{savedfootnotenumber}]{Second note}

Answer (score 80):

The most consistent way to do this is to keep the footnotes as they are but supply the `[frame]` option to them.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}
Some text for the first column and a test footnote\footnote[frame]{A test footnote in the first column}
\column{.5\textwidth}
Some text for the second column and a test footnote\footnote[frame]{A test footnote in the second column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output as intended with standard footnote syntax]

Comment: In order to prevent the long footnote from overlapping the menu icons, you can add double back slash before the closing `}`

Comment: Is it possible to use something like `\renewcommand<>{\footnote} ...` to make this the default? I am using pandoc and the only way (as I see it) to enforce this is to redefine footnote command in the preamble.

Answer (score 0):

At first I removed this answer because I wasn't sure what you wanted.  You might
want to change the MWE above, I don't know.  Anyway, this works for me to give
a single footnote.  Just call the footnote after explicitly closing the columns.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{img1}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{img2}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
*\footnote{Your footnote text.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Works for me.  What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I'm using pandoc so I wanted the solution to work by default on all footnotes with a `renewcommand` (just as asked by @jadelord in a comment below @andreas post). But it is nothing simple, because of all the layers that beamer adds to `footnote` and `renewcommand` in order to manage overlay specifications (and pandoc sends an overlay specification to `footnote`). Ideally, the pandoc code should be updated. The only solution I found is to copy/paste the `footnote` `renewcommand` from beamer source code and force the `frame` option. Here is my code for the record.

```
\makeatletter
 \renewcommand<>{\footnote}[1][]{%
  \let\beamer@footnotetext=\@footnotetext%
  \let\beamer@mpfn=\@mpfn%
  \let\beamer@thempfn=\thempfn%
  \let\beamer@kvorig=\KV@errx%
  \let\beamer@xkvorig=\XKV@err
  \def\beamer@footarg{}%
  \def\KV@errx##1{\edef\beamer@footarg{\@tempa}}%
  \def\XKV@err##1{\edef\beamer@footarg{\XKV@tkey}}%
  \setkeys{beamerfootnote}{frame}%
  \let\KV@errx=\beamer@kvorig%
  \let\XKV@errx=\beamer@xkvorig
  \ifx\beamer@footarg\@empty%
    \def\beamer@next{\stepcounter\beamer@mpfn
      \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\beamer@thempfn}%
      \@footnotemark\beamer@footnotetext#2}%
  \else%
    \def\beamer@next{%
      \begingroup
        \csname c@\beamer@mpfn\endcsname\beamer@footarg\relax
        \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\beamer@thempfn}%
      \endgroup
      \@footnotemark\beamer@footnotetext#2}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@next}
\makeatother
```