# Footfullcitetext and beamer: incremental numbering

Tags: beamer, biblatex

It has been shown in this answer [How to display the footnote in the bottom of the slide while using \columns?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86650/how-to-display-the-footnote-in-the-bottom-of-the-slide-while-using-columns) how not to break the column environment of beamer when placing a footnote via `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext{<>}`.

However this doesn't apply well to citations, as usually they have an index (unique for the whole document) that is different from the footnote index (per frame). A possible trick is to force the footnote number via `\footnotemark[25]` and `\footnotetext[25]{\fullcite}`, but this is not convenient at all.

I read in [Undesired Placement of Footnotes in Blocks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45437/undesired-placement-of-footnotes-in-blocks) that a useful definition could be added to beamer, `footfullcitetext`. However if there is more than one citation per page there are the same problems as above with `\footnotemark`.

Any idea how to use a citation number that is incremented automatically over the whole presentation?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend = biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}\usebeamerfont*{footnote mark}\@thefnmark}}}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\@textsuperscript{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}\usebeamerfont*{footnote mark}\@thefnmark}\enspace\usebeamerfont*{footnote} #1}
\makeatother
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\fullcite{westfahl:space}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}
Here is text \footnotemark. % this writes ref01 in place
\column{.5\textwidth}
Blabla and another ref \footnotemark.
\end{columns}

\footfullcitetext{westfahl:space}
\footfullcitetext{angenendt}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is always the same when you have two (or more `\footnotemark` commands; you have to take care of the numbers “manually”:

```
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footfullcitetext{westfahl:space}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footfullcitetext{angenendt}
```

[image]