# Add square brackets to footfullcite in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I used `\footfullcite` to insert two citations in beamer, and got this,

[image]

How do I add square brackets to the reference number, and make them become `[1][2]` instead of `12`?

---

Here is a MWE.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{References.bib}
@article{ahlswede2000network,
  title={Network information flow},
  author={Ahlswede, Rudolf and Cai, Ning and Li, Shuo-Yen Robert and Yeung, Raymond W},
  journal={Information Theory, IEEE Transactions on},
  volume={46},
  number={4},
  pages={1204--1216},
  year={2000},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
@article{katti2008xors,
  title={{XORs in the air: practical wireless network coding}},
  author={Katti, Sachin and Rahul, Hariharan and Hu, Wenjun and Katabi, Dina and M{\'e}dard, Muriel and Crowcroft, Jon},
  journal={IEEE/ACM Transactions on Networking (ToN)},
  volume={16},
  number={3},
  pages={497--510},
  year={2008},
  publisher={IEEE Press}
}
\end{filecontents*}

%%% 

\documentclass[t, 11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{References}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]{XOR network coding}
XOR network coding \footfullcite{ahlswede2000network} \footfullcite{katti2008xors}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{(\arabic{footnote})}` help?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\arabic{footnote}]}` with your edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> With a little help from [Footfullcitetext and beamer: incremental numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234306/36296)

To add the square brackets, you can alter the definition of

- `\@makefnmark` for the number displayed in the text
- `\@makefntext` for the number displayed in the footnote

---

```
\begin{filecontents*}{References.bib}
@article{ahlswede2000network,
  title={Network information flow},
  author={Ahlswede, Rudolf and Cai, Ning and Li, Shuo-Yen Robert and Yeung, Raymond W},
  journal={Information Theory, IEEE Transactions on},
  volume={46},
  number={4},
  pages={1204--1216},
  year={2000},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
@article{katti2008xors,
  title={{XORs in the air: practical wireless network coding}},
  author={Katti, Sachin and Rahul, Hariharan and Hu, Wenjun and Katabi, Dina and M{\'e}dard, Muriel and Crowcroft, Jon},
  journal={IEEE/ACM Transactions on Networking (ToN)},
  volume={16},
  number={3},
  pages={497--510},
  year={2008},
  publisher={IEEE Press}
}
\end{filecontents*}

%%% 

\documentclass[t, 11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{References}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}\usebeamerfont*{footnote mark}[\@thefnmark]}}}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\@textsuperscript{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}\usebeamerfont*{footnote mark}[\@thefnmark]}\enspace\usebeamerfont*{footnote} #1}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]{XOR network coding}
XOR network coding \footfullcite{ahlswede2000network} \footfullcite{katti2008xors}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

[image]