# How to format the \footfullcite in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes

I am using `beamer` and I want the footnote in the PDF to be superscript like

[image: ![enter image description here]

But in the footer, I want it shown as

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

% Redefine the \@makefnmark command to add space between label and text
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]\enspace}}
\makeatother

% Change the font size for footnotes
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Acknowledgments}
  This is a citation\footfullcite{LenTayQui:J16}. 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{References}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the future, make sure to include the bibliography package you are using as a tag i.e `biblatex`, we are lucky on this site to have experts so it helps people find your question if it is tagged appropriately :)

Comment: It is worth noting that `\footfullcite` only generates a footnote containing the full bibliography entry. The footnote number need not correspond to any citation label/number that is assigned for example by a numeric citation style. In particular several `\footfullcite` calls to the same entry will generate different numbers. (This is not as obvious here since your style choice and `beamer` usually don't number the bibliography at the end. But if there were numbers in the bibliography they could not be guaranteed to correspond to the footnote numbers at all.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight variation of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368760/36296 :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}\usebeamerfont*{footnote mark}[\@thefnmark]}}}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}\usebeamerfont*{footnote mark}[\@thefnmark]}\usebeamerfont*{footnote} #1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Acknowledgments}
  This is a citation\footfullcite{knuth:ct}. 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{References}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is what I want.

Comment: @Harry You're welcome!