# Citation beamer

Tags: beamer, citing

I need inline citations in `beamer`. However, when I use the `columns` environment, the numbers of the indices appear wrong as in picture.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}{Introduction}{}
      \begin{columns}
      \column{0.5\textwidth}
         cite1 \footnotemark
      \column{0.5\textwidth}
         cite2 \footnotemark
      \end{columns}
      \footcitetext{vine2006google}
      \footcitetext{jacso2008google}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer presented here combines these two answers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86651/118712 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135950/118712 .

You can use the `fullentry{}` command provided by `biblatex` in combination with `\footnotetext[]{}`. You will need to manage the numbering of the footnotes manually though.

Note, that I changed the backend to the more contemporary `biber`, because that is my default. It should work with the `bibtex` backend as well.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
    @article{vine2006google,
        author = {John Doe},
        year = {2021},
        journal = {Science},
        pages = {1--2}
    }

    @article{jacso2008google,
    author = {Jane Doe},
    year = {2021},
    journal = {Science},
    pages = {1--2}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Introduction}{}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{0.5\textwidth}
            cite1 \footnotemark
            \column{0.5\textwidth}
            cite2 \footnotemark
        \end{columns}
        \footnotetext[1]{\fullcite{vine2006google}}
        \footnotetext[2]{\fullcite{jacso2008google}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Looks like this:

[image]