# Beamer: combining footnote in one column with figure in the other one

Tags: beamer, graphics, horizontal-alignment, footnotes

I'd like to put a figure next to a list which contains a footnote. Without the footnote everything works fine. But when I add the footnote, the figure gets shifted to the right and partly appears to be outside the frame margin. I'd like to put the figure back to where it was before I added the footnote. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{Title}

\begin{columns}[c]

    \begin{column}[r]{5cm}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item The first item
        \item The second item\footnote{A footnote}
        \item The third item
        \end{itemize} 
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}[l]{5cm}
        {\rule{2cm}{2cm}}%
        %\includegraphics
    \end{column}

\end{columns}   

}

\end{document}
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: you could use `\footnotemark[num]` in the item and `\footnotetext[num]{text}` outside of columns. check out [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44217/how-can-i-stop-footcite-from-hijacking-my-beamer-columns)

Comment: @jenson_bo unfortunately, in this case, `\footnotemark`, `\footnotetext` doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Gonzalo For me it does. Did you add `\footnotetext` after `\end{columns}`?

Comment: @jenson_bo but then the footnote text will be moved to the end of the frame which could be achieved simply by using the `frame` option for `\footnote`, as in `\footnote[frame]{A footnote}`. I assumed that AnjaM's intent was to have the footnote text close to the itemized list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\begin{columns}[c]

    \begin{column}[l]{5cm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item The first item
        \item The second item\footnote{A footnote}
        \item The third item
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage} 
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}[l]{5cm}
        \rule{2cm}{2cm}%
        %\includegraphics
    \end{column}

\end{columns}   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the third slide:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works!
Do you know why the figure shifted without the minipage environment? I don't really understand why the minipage environment changes the behaviour.