# \footcite only printing BibTeX key

Tags: beamer, bibtex, citing, miktex, texworks

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXworks. When I compile the beamer document with footnote references it only returns the text that's in the braces for the `\footnote` command in the footnote and not an actual reference.

Minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%THEME
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

%BIBTEX
\usepackage[style=verbose,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{methods,
    author= "A.G. Schwartz and J.H. Lipner and J.D. Pasteris and G.M. Genin and S. Thomopoulos",
    title = "Muscle loading is necessary for the formation of a functional tendon enthesis",
    journal = "Bone",
    year = "2013",
    volume = "55",
    number = "1",
    pages = "44-51",
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Recap}

\begin{itemize}
\item This is a recap slide\footcite{methods}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Gives me this:

[image]

---

I even tried to copy and paste the example in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44231/61165) answer and it gives me same type of error: just prints "Taflove2000" in the footnote.

It's got to be something to do with the way I'm compiling it. I've tried it with miktex-pdftex.exe with arguments

```
$synctexoption
--shell-escape
-undump=pdflatex
$fullname
```

which is what I usually use. But I've also tried it with  texify.exe and arguments

```
--pdf
--tex-option=$synctexoption
$fullname
```

What should I be using?

Comment: did you run `biber` after `pdflatex`? The full compilation workshop should be `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex`.

Comment: @Guido, I do not. How would I do that in TeXworks? I'm still trying to learn this all.

Comment: Alternatively add `backend=bibtex` to the options of `biblatex`.

Comment: Alternatively see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations and  also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number?rq=1

Comment: @Guido I followed the instructions in that link and get the following error `Entity: line 1959: parser error : expected '>'
      </bcf:constra
                   ^
Entity: line 1959: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: constraint line 1954 and constra
      </bcf:constra
                   ^
INFO - This is Biber 1.8
INFO - Logfile is 'pres2.blg'
INFO - Reading 'pres2.bcf'` and nothing changes if I add the `backend=bibtex` option.

Comment: Remove all auxiliary files. Then can you try from the command line/terminal? If you include `backend=bibtex` you have to run `pdflatex pres2` then `bibtex pres2` and then `pdflatex pres2`. Without that line the second step is `biber pres2`.