# \cite and \footnote in together in Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibtex

generally the references are kept at the last slide and cited using `\cite` command. I feel that this kind of notation is little difficult to understand from the point of an audience. Mostly, I use `\footnote` command, because it shows the reference at footer in same slide, which makes easier to understand. But `\footnote` can't print from bib file and therefore I always ended up putting one complete reference with `\footnote`. See below an example-

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\title[Test]{Test} 
\author{Author} 
\institute[]{Institute}
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Citation}
    This statement requires citation \cite{tobin1964commercial}

    But the way I want is \footnote{Tobin, James. Commercial banks as creators of" money.". Cowles Foundation for Research in Economics at Yale University, 1964.} %\footnote{tobin1964commercial}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{References}
    \bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
    \bibliography{bibfile}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is how the generated PDF looks-
[image]

What I want is a way, so that I can use `\footnote` together with `\cite` command, something like `\footnote{tobin1964commercial}`. And this should show the complete reference in the footer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`\footcite` might be a solution for you:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% only for this example, otherwise in .bib file
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@TECHREPORT{RePEc:cwl:cwldpp:159,
    title = {Commercial Banks as Creators of 'Money'},
    author = {Tobin, James},
    year = {1963},
    institution = {Cowles Foundation for Research in Economics, Yale University},
    type = {Cowles Foundation Discussion Papers},
    number = {159},
    url = {http://EconPapers.repec.org/RePEc:cwl:cwldpp:159}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
    Text text \footcite{RePEc:cwl:cwldpp:159}
 \end{frame}

 \begin{frame}
     \printbibliography
 \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly. Is it possible to have the last reference slide as well? I would prefer to see the references with the same index as appeared in the slide. If possible. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RaviJoshi Sure, see my edit.

Comment: Not able to compile. Getting following error `This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015) The top-level auxiliary file: ppt.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file ppt.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file ppt.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file ppt.aux (There were 3 error messages)`

Comment: @RaviJoshi As this solution uses `biblatex` this has to be compiles with `biber` and not `bibtex`. If you don't have `biber` you can try with `\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` instead. If you witch from bibtex to biber it is easiest to remove all the axillary files and compile from clean.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. I am using `Texmaker 4.5` with `Texlive 2015` on `Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64` OS. I see neither `biber` nor `biblatex` in `Texmaker 4.5`. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. `biblatex` is there. Thanks a lot. It is working now.

Comment: If you use multiple columns, the footnote will mess up with the layout. 
In this case, a better solution is the one by egreg:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44230/144692