# Beamer contextual citation in footnote

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibtex, citing

I want to produce the following format when citing on my slides using Beamer.

[image]

Right now I am producing this manually, but I want latex+bibtex to do this automatically. How can I achieve this?

My file looks like:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Hannover}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\theenumiv]}

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{center page number}
{   
    \vspace{-12pt}
    \hspace*{6.4cm}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in foot}%
    {\insertpagenumber\,/\,\insertpresentationendpage}
    \hspace*{6cm}\vskip2pt
    }
\begin{document}
\frame{
In addition, we provide guidance in the application of the method for experimental groups\cite{HarrisSongKiang2007,YuGuptaLiuEtAl2012,WedekindReguera2008}.     

\footnotetext{\tiny\hspace{-16.5pt}\cite{HarrisSongKiang2007} N. C. Harries et al., Phys Rev Lett., 99,2007\\  \cite{YuGuptaLiuEtAl2012} H. Yu et al., Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci.,109, 2012.\\ \cite{WedekindReguera2008} J. Wedekind and D. Reguera. J. Phys. Chem. B, 112, 2008.\\ }
}

\section*{References}

\begin{multicols}{2}[
\frametitle{\insertsection}
    \usebeamertemplate{frametitle}]
    \tiny{\bibliographystyle{unsrt}}
    \bibliography{BibliographyDataBase}

\end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've tried Natbib and BibLatex with no success.

Comment: Are you aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340080/121799)?

Comment: That method doesn't allow me to identify individual citations with numbers [1] Jack, 2019. [2] Jonh, 2017. etc. in the footnote.

Comment: This is surprisingly tricky. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20787/35864 would be one of the `biblatex` standard approaches for such an issue. Maybe it can help you already (not sure if and where `beamer` could interfere). Specifically for `beamer` we have https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45406/35864. Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386707/35864

Comment: Questions like this come up from time to time, but I have yet to find a fully satisfying solution. Unfortunately, I can't even manage to find some of the questions I seem to remember...

Answer (score 1):

I solve it with biblatex + defining new commands in the preamble

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Hannover}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=bibtex,url=false,isbn=false,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\AtNextBibliography{\tiny}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{author}{#1\addcomma}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1\addcomma}
\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{}

\AtEveryBibitem{%  suppress unnecessary fields 
    \clearfield{pages}%
    \clearfield{number}
    \clearfield{doi}%
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{eprint}%
    \clearfield{abstract}
}

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{center page number}
{   
    \vspace{-12pt}
    \hspace*{6.4cm}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in foot}%
    {\insertpagenumber\,/\,\insertpresentationendpage}
    \hspace*{6cm}\vskip2pt
    }
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel} 
% This comand extracts the info necesary from fields on citation
\newcommand{\fcite}[1]{\cite{#1}\, \citeauthor{#1}, \citefield{#1}{journaltitle}, \citeyear{#1}.}

\begin{document}

\frame{

        In addition, we provide guidance in the application of the 
    method for experimental 
    groups\cite{HarrisSongKiang2007,YuGuptaLiuEtAl2012,WedekindReguera2008}
 \footnotetext{\tiny\fcite{HarrisSongKiang2007}\fcite{YuGuptaLiuEtAl2012}\fcite{WedekindReguera2008}}.

    }
    \section*{References}


\begin{multicols}{2}[
\frametitle{\insertsection}
    \usebeamertemplate{frametitle}]
    \printbibliography
\end{multicols} 

\begin{end}
```

The result is the same and saves a lot of time in formatting individual frames footnotes.