# Unable to get the article cited in beamer the using the footcite coomand

Tags: beamer, biblatex, biber, frame, footcite

I am trying to cite an article on my beamer slide, but it's not getting cited properly. Please see the code and output below. Please note that the first reference cited as techreport is cited properly, but the second reference cited as the article is neither being cited nor appearing under references. I have tried using the idea presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340056/cite-and-footnote-in-together-in-beamer) but unfortunately cannot comment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
% only for this example, otherwise in .bib file
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@TECHREPORT{RePEc:cwl:cwldpp:159,
    title = {Commercial Banks as Creators of 'Money'},
    author = {Tobin, James},
   year = {1963},
    institution = {Cowles Foundation for Research in Economics, Yale University},
    type = {Cowles Foundation Discussion Papers},
    number = {159},
    url = {http://EconPapers.repec.org/RePEc:cwl:cwldpp:159}
}

@article{oku2004continuous,
  title={Continuous chemoselective methylation of functionalized amines and diols with supercritical methanol over solid acid and acid- base bifunctional catalysts},
  author={Oku, Tomoharu and Arita, Yoshitaka and Tsuneki, Hideaki and Ikariya, Takao},
  journal={Journal of the American Chemical Society},
  volume={126},
  number={23},
  pages={7368--7377},
  year={2004},
  publisher={ACS Publications}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{Introduction}
    Text text \footcite{RePEc:cwl:cwldpp:159}

    sample text 2 \footcite{oku2004continuous}
 \end{frame}

 \begin{frame}{References}
     \printbibliography
 \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the latex code in Overleaf]

Comment: You're example works fine for me with up-to-date texlive 2022 https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7Shq.png

Comment: (btw: nice minimal working example!)

Comment: Can you show your .blg file?

Comment: Off-topic: there is one space too much in `acid- base`

Comment: Firstly, I am using online overleaf editor for preparing the slides. Now when I started a new project and re-used the same code, output has come as expected. However, if I try to edit the references, it doesn't get reflected in the output pdf. As an example, I changed the article title of the second reference. You can access the overleaf file from here https://www.overleaf.com/4138734175vfghmhtrpfqf. The output image is available here: https://freeimage.host/i/sample.H9hsct1

Comment: In https://www.overleaf.com/project/63763c5858970956fecd957e the problem is that a new project will automatically use the latest texlive version overleaf has (texlive from summer 2022) and this new latex version comes with a build in filecontents environment. The previously required filecontents package now basically does nothing. The problem is that the syntax of the filecontents environment build into latex is different. You now need `\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}` if you want to overwrite an already existing file

Comment: So, if you first created your example with only one references and added the second one later, this probably never got added to the bib file.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks a lot for your timely help.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your overleaf project, the problem is that a new project will automatically use the latest texlive version overleaf has (texlive from summer 2022) and this latex version comes with a build in `filecontents` environment. The previously required `filecontents` package now basically does nothing and let's you just use the build in version from latex.

However, the syntax of the `filecontents` environment build into latex is different than the one from the `filecontents` package. You now need

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
...
\end{filecontents*}
```

If you don't use the new syntax, an already existing file will no longer be overwritten and thus changes, like adding a new entry or changing the title, won't be reflected in the .bib file.

Comment: It works like a wonder. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Priyam You're welcome!