# BibLatex citation numbers in footnotes of Beamer frames are wrong. How to correct?

Tags: beamer, biblatex

[In this SE post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44217/how-can-i-stop-footcite-from-hijacking-my-beamer-columns/44230#44230), there is code from `lockstep` showing how to put in BibLatex citations in footnotes in Beamer pages with columns.

It seems to work well if there is only one citation in one Beamer Page.

However, there seems to be two problems:

(1) when there are multiple citaitons in one page. The numbers in the footnotes are wrong (the numbers outside the footnotes are fine), as shown in frame 2 and 3 in the compiled Beamer PDF. Specifically, the entries in the footnotes have a same preceding number. Could you help to comment how to solve this problem ?

(2) when the same citation is cited across different Beamer pages, the citation number is incremented. Is it possible to use the same number for the single citation ?

Many thanks !

shell command to run

```
rm MWE1.aux MWE1.bbl MWE1.bcf MWE1.blg MWE1.log MWE1.nav MWE1.out MWE1.pdf MWE1.snm MWE1.toc MWE1.run.xml ; xelatex MWE1.tex && biber MWE1 && xelatex MWE1.tex && xelatex MWE1.tex
```

MWE1.tex modified based on `lockstep`'s post

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[width=4em]{PaloAlto}
\usecolortheme{crane}

\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{\vspace{-6pt}\advance\hsize-0.5cm}{\vspace{6pt}}
\makeatletter
% Alternative A: footnote rule
\renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern -3pt \hrule \@width 2in \kern 8.6pt}
% Alternative B: no footnote rule
% \renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern 6pt}
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose,autocite=footnote,citestyle=authortitle]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Taflove2000,
    Day = {30},
    Edition = {2},
    Month = {jun},
    Publisher = {Artech House Publishers},
    author = {Taflove, Allen and Hagness, Susan C.},
    title = {Computational Electrodynamics: The Finite-Difference Time-Domain Method},
    year = {2000},
}
@Book{label2,
    Day = {30},
    Edition = {2},
    Month = {jun},
    Publisher = {Artech House Publishers},
    author = {Jordan, Michael and James, LeBron},
    title = {Computational NBA},
    year = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{The FDTD Method}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Discretization of both space and time by central differences.
      \item Yee Cell 1.\footnotemark 
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \rule{0.9\columnwidth}{2cm}% placeholder for graphic
      \caption{Unit Yee Cell.}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\footcitetext{Taflove2000}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{The FDTD Method}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Discretization of both space and time by central differences.\footnotemark 
      \item Yee Cell 1.\footnotemark 
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \rule{0.9\columnwidth}{2cm}% placeholder for graphic
      \caption{Unit Yee Cell.}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\footcitetext{Taflove2000}
\footcitetext{label2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{The FDTD Method}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Discretization of both space and time by central differences.\footnotemark 
      \item Yee Cell 1.\footnotemark 
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \rule{0.9\columnwidth}{2cm}% placeholder for graphic
      \caption{Unit Yee Cell.}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\footcitetext{Taflove2000}
\footcitetext{Taflove2000,label2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution, only for your first question:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[width=4em]{PaloAlto}
\usecolortheme{crane}

\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{\vspace{-6pt}\advance\hsize-0.5cm}{\vspace{6pt}}
\makeatletter
% Alternative A: footnote rule
\renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern -3pt \hrule \@width 2in \kern 8.6pt}
% Alternative B: no footnote rule
% \renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern 6pt}
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose,autocite=footnote,citestyle=authortitle]{biblatex}

\newcounter{colcites}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Taflove2000,
    Day = {30},
    Edition = {2},
    Month = {jun},
    Publisher = {Artech House Publishers},
    author = {Taflove, Allen and Hagness, Susan C.},
    title = {Computational Electrodynamics: The Finite-Difference Time-Domain Method},
    year = {2000},
}
@Book{label2,
    Day = {30},
    Edition = {2},
    Month = {jun},
    Publisher = {Artech House Publishers},
    author = {Jordan, Michael and James, LeBron},
    title = {Computational NBA},
    year = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{The FDTD Method}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Discretization of both space and time by central differences.
      \item Yee Cell 1.\footnotemark 
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \rule{0.9\columnwidth}{2cm}% placeholder for graphic
      \caption{Unit Yee Cell.}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\footcitetext{Taflove2000}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{The FDTD Method}
\setcounter{colcites}{0}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Discretization of both space and time by central differences.\footnotemark\addtocounter{colcites}{1} 
      \item Yee Cell 1.\footnotemark\addtocounter{colcites}{1}  
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \rule{0.9\columnwidth}{2cm}% placeholder for graphic
      \caption{Unit Yee Cell.}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}

\addtocounter{footnote}{-\thecolcites}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footcitetext[\thefootnote]{Taflove2000}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footcitetext[\thefootnote]{label2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```