# footnotecite or footnotemark-footcitetext generates incorrect citation number in beamer when there is a citation in the frame title

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing, footnotes

I'm trying to generate footnote citation in a beamer column.
Currently, possible solutions to properly put the citation information at the bottom of the page can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44217/how-can-i-stop-footcite-from-hijacking-my-beamer-columns).
But, if you have citations in frametitle this, it will incorrectly number the instance that uses footnotemark-footcitetext in the column (see MWE's below).
Both of the MWE's will produce them same output even when the citations are swapped around. Any ideas of how to overcome this?

### MWE (1):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{test,
        title={NA},
        author={NA},
        journal={NA},
        volume={1},
        number={1},
        pages={1},
        year={1},
        publisher={NA}
    }
    @article{example,
        title={ANAasd},
        author={ANAasd},
        journal={ANAasd},
        volume={1},
        number={1},
        pages={1},
        year={2},
        publisher={NA}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[usenames]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\mode<presentation>{}

\usepackage[
citestyle=numeric,
style = authoryear,
backend=biber,
sorting = nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Great paper\footcite{test}}
        \begin{columns}[T]
        \column{.45\linewidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Citation here does not work\footnotemark
        \end{itemize}
    \end{columns}
\footcitetext{example}
    \end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{References}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### MWE (2):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{test,
        title={NA},
        author={NA},
        journal={NA},
        volume={1},
        number={1},
        pages={1},
        year={1},
        publisher={NA}
    }
    @article{example,
        title={ANAasd},
        author={ANAasd},
        journal={ANAasd},
        volume={1},
        number={1},
        pages={1},
        year={2},
        publisher={NA}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[usenames]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\mode<presentation>{}

\usepackage[
citestyle=numeric,
style = authoryear,
backend=biber,
sorting = nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Great paper\footcite{example}}
        \begin{columns}[T]
        \column{.45\linewidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Citation here does not work\footnotemark
        \end{itemize}
    \end{columns}
\footcitetext{test}
    \end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{References}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could do

```
\documentclass[usenames]{beamer}

\usepackage[
  citestyle=numeric,
  style = authoryear,
  backend=biber,
  sorting = nyt
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Great paper\footnotemark[1]}
        \vphantom{\footcite{test}}
        \begin{columns}[T]
        \column{.45\linewidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Citation here does not work\footnote[frame]{\cite{example}}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{References}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]