# How do I adjust the width of Beamer's footnote "area"?

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I have a Beamer template with a vertical "ToC bar" along the right side. I have the problem that when I insert footnote citations (e.g. `biblatex`'  `\footfullcite`), the resulting footnote protrudes into the ToC bar on the right.
This leads me to suspect that footnotes are typeset in a different "area" of a frame than the main content (since the main frame content does not "invade" the navigation bar).
How do I adjust the width of this footnote area so that long footnotes do not protrude into the ToC bar on the right?

Comment: Using the `Goettingen` theme (which features a sidebar on the right), footnotes don't protrude into the the sidebar, so you'll have to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Note that the *vertical* positioning of footnotes is problematic; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5852/beamer-footnote-text-collides-with-navigation-symbols

Comment: A minimal working example involves a full beamer template - this one: http://kom.aau.dk/~jkn/latex/latex.php#beamer_aausidebar. Can I expect people to want to install that to check my example?

Comment: Thanks [lockstep](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep), that post on the vertical positioning seems related. It looks like I might be able to use that `\addtobeamertemplate` command to tweak it, but I don't know how to reduce the available horizontal space there.
Maybe I could just redefine the footnote template to contain a sufficiently narrow minipage, but I guess that is a pretty dirty hack...

Answer (score 3):

OK, I seem to have found a solution that works, but I still think it might be a dirty hack...
Inspired by [lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep)'s question cited in the comments, I gambled that this could be done using `\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}`.

I poked around Beamer's basic definitions and found `\newcommand<>\beamer@framefootnotetext[1]{...` in `beamerbaseframecomponents.sty` where I found `\hsize0.85\paperwidth` which seems to define the footnote "area" width.

So, I came up with the following solution:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{\hsize\beamerfoottmplength}{}
```

where I have tweaked \beamerfoottmplength to the desired width.

Comment: It turns out this may have been a non-problem after all. I had compiled my Beamer document using TexLive 2011 where the footnote protrusion problem occurred. Now I have tried compiling using TexLive 2012 and here, Beamer seems to have been updated so that this problem has disappeared. See also https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/200/width-of-footnote-in-a-sidebar-theme#comment-1488103