# changing footnote box color in beamer?

Tags: beamer, color, footnotes

How can i change footnote box color in beamer? I can set the text color and other properties but unable to change the color of the box. Meanwhile, how can i adjust the length of the footnote?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Beamer command `\setbeamercolor{}`. In this case use `\setbeamercolor{footlinecolor}{fg=<color1>, bg=<color2>}`. You might also want to change the `\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=<color>, bg=<color>}` and `\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=<color>, bg=<color>}`. As for the width have a look here: [How do I adjust the width of Beamer's footnote "area"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95983/how-do-i-adjust-the-width-of-beamers-footnote-area)

Comment: I am unable to modify the changes:
This is my code:

Comment: \setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
 \hrulefill
  \hbox{%
 \setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=black,bg=yellow}
  \pgfsetfillopacity{0.25}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1.00\paperwidth,ht=4.00ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
  \hspace*{1em}\insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{30ex}
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{9em}
  \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{3em}  
  \end{beamercolorbox}}% 
  \vskip4pt%
}

Comment: I used the commands you provided just before this code.

Comment: @user83144 Please don't add the code in comments; esit your question and add it there.