# Footnotes (e.g. citations) in the footline of beamer frames?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes

I like to have references to images etc. on my beamer slides printed in the footline area of the frame, i.e. close to the bottom:

[image: Testframe with reference in the footline]

In the example I create the footnote 'manually' like this:

```
\begin{frame}{Testframe}
   It is known\textsuperscript{1}
   \footlinetext{\textsuperscript{1}en.wikipedia.org}
\end{frame}
```

where the '\footlinetext' command has been created according to [How do I insert text into the footline of a specific slide in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5491/how-do-i-insert-text-into-the-footline-of-a-specific-slide-in-beamer)

My question is now: Can I redirect the output generated by '\footnote' commands to the footline via '\footlinetext' ? Specifically, I'd like to use Biblatex citation commands such as '\footfullcite' automatically generate the footnotemark and to fill the footline with the reference's information from the bibtex database.

So this code should produce the same output than above:

```
\begin{frame}{Testframe}
   It is known\footfullcite{wiki-en}
\end{frame}
```

assuming that 'wiki-en' is the Bibtex key for en.wikipedia.org

Comment: I don't think that you should do such things in a presentation. If people start to read a frame like a normal text they will no longer hear what you are saying. References etc should better go in accompaigning material.

Comment: I totally agree with you that slides should not be like a book. I also have to admit that my example was poorly chosen. The normal case is that I have one (or rarely, a couple of) figure(s) on a slide. But sometimes these figure are not mine own but from another source. I think the source should be given on the slide and that the footline is a quite elegant place to have it.

Comment: With graphics I like the idea even less. If you must mention the source: put a small text on the graphics itself.