# Add text in the footline of a specific beamer frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, textpos

I'm using my university beamer template to create a presentation.

The footline of the template includes a blue bar and the university logo.
In other presentations I've created, I was using the `textpos` package to place citations or other notes on the blue footline bar; however, I've noticed that it clashes with some other packages I'm using for this presentation (e.g., when using `hf-tikz`, the color of the text enclosed in the boxes created by `hf-tikz` get the same color I defined in the `textblock` environment).

The MWE is the following (the footline definition is delimited by the dashed comment lines):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}             %internationalization
\usepackage{tikz}                       %inline graphics
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[customcolors,markings,shade,beamer]{hf-tikz}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

% ----------------------------
%footline definition
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{body}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    %blue background rectangle
    \node [white,draw,fill=blue,minimum width=1.01\paperwidth,minimum 
           height=.067\paperheight,anchor=south west,xshift=-.3mm,yshift=-.25mm,text width=0.965\paperwidth]
    at (current page.south west) {};
    %logo
    \node [anchor= east,inner 
           sep=0,xshift=-.03\paperwidth,yshift=.073\paperheight] at (current page.south east) { LOGO here
    %\includegraphics[width=.16\textwidth]{kuleuven_CMYK_logo.pdf}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}               
}   
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[body]
% ----------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example slide}
    \begin{align*}
        \tikzmarkin<1->{firsteq}\mathbf{F}(t+1) &= \mathbf{F}(k) + \mathbf{N}(k) \tikzmarkend{firsteq}\\
        \tikzmarkin<2->[set fill color=green!50!lime!30,set border color=green!40!black]{seceq}\mathbf{F}(t+1) &= \mathbf{F}(k) + \mathbf{N}(k)  \tikzmarkend{seceq}
    \end{align*}

    \begin{textblock*}{11cm}(0.25cm,9.15cm)%
        \scriptsize
        \color{white}Nice footline comment
    \end{textblock*}%


\end{frame}
\end{document}    
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example slide}
blah blah blah blah
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and you can see how the `textblock` command causes problems by changing the color of everything within the blocks defined by `hf-tikz`. The problem doesn't exist if the `textblock` command is commented out.

I tried to use different solutions found in other threads here on `tex.stackexchange` (e.g. [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5491/how-do-i-insert-text-into-the-footline-of-a-specific-slide-in-beamer)) but none worked for my case. I suspect this is for the same reason that just putting a node from within a frame on the part of the frame occupied by the footline doesn't work, i.e. the footline colored bar would be placed on top of the node.

If someone has an idea of how to make this work, either with or without `textpos`, it would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the problem was simply due to my carelessness of forgetting to brace the `color` command in the `textblock` command. This way there's no more 'leaking' of color. Sorry about that.

```
    \begin{textblock*}{11cm}(0.25cm,9.15cm)%
        {\scriptsize\color{white}Nice footline comment}
    \end{textblock*}%
```