# Include presentation slides numbers on beamer notes

Tags: beamer, notes

I would like to include the number of the presentation slide in the beamer note slide, so I would have a reference if I decide to generate slides and notes separately.

In the MWE below, I have three different types of slides: one with multiple note-pages, one without notes, and with only one note-page. Would it be possible to add the number of the presentation slide in which these notes are located? Possibly in the right lower corner as in the main slides?

If I were to generate a pdf with only the notes using `\setbeameroption{show only notes}`, I wouldn't have any idea about what is the corresponding presentation slide for each note. This becomes more relevant when there are slides with multiple note-pages or without notes, as the mapping between presentation slides and note slides wouldn't be one to one.

Note that I choose a plain style for the notes, as the standard style takes a lot of space. I know the thumbnail in the standard style could serve as a reference, but it is too big for what I need.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
% Repeat slide title
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{%
    \pagecolor{yellow!15}
    \vfill
    \begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
        {\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\insertframetitle\par}
        \insertnote
    \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Slide with several note pages}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item There are too many things to say in this slide
        \item That is why I need several pages for notes
    \end{itemize}
    % Notes
    \note<1>{Hello from note 1}
    \note<2>{Hello from note 2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide without notes}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item No notes in this slide
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide with only one note page}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Just one note here
        \item And that's all
    \end{itemize}
    % Notes
    \note{Hello from note 1}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it is a bit weird to answer my own question but I now have a solution. It uses a combination of the beamer provided `\AtEndNote` and the `\footlineextra` command suggested here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5558/77059 by @LJN. I changed the alignment and used the beamer command `\insertframenumber`.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\author{A. Author}
\title{The Presentation}

% Provides the footlineextra command
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\footlineextra}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[yshift=1ex,anchor=south east] at (current page.south east) {\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Notes
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right} % Both
% Coloring note-pages
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{\pagecolor{yellow!15}\insertnote}
% Note-pages title
\AtBeginNote{\vspace{0.325cm}{\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\insertframetitle} \par}
% Note-pages footer
\AtEndNote{\footlineextra{\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}Slide \insertframenumber}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Slide with several note pages}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item There are too many things to say in this slide
        \item That is why I need several pages for notes
    \end{itemize}
    % Notes
    \note<1>{Hello from note 1}
    \note<2>{Hello from note 2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide without notes}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item No notes in this slide
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide with only one note page}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Just one note here
        \item And that's all
    \end{itemize}
    % Notes
    \note{Hello from note 1}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And this part of the output:

[image]